# Saveguard against device removal in os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, file-writing

OSX 10.10.3 MacBook Pro 15-Zoll

I'm currently writing an mac app which is writing files to a mounted device.
Everyone knows not to (physically) disconnect a device while using it but sometimes it'll happen anyways, so i tested my app's behavior.

My app behaved reasonably (didn't freezed etc.) but there was something different happening.
The path of my device is

```
'/Volumes/MyDevice'
```

and after i reconnected the device there where two entries in the finder

```
'/Volumes/MyDevice' 
'/Volumes/MyDevice'
```

but one of the entries was an *empty folder* the other was a mounted device.

And when i checked the url of the device with NSLog it said

```
'/Volumes/MyDevice%201'
```

I use NSFileManager to access the file system.

Does someone know what this behavior means ? 
Or if there are some special tactics with unmountable devices ?

Comment: A good approach would be to register to `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` and listen to device notifications in order to point to the right devices.

Comment: normal, the mount point doesn't get removed, and thus a new one is created

Comment: @MatteoPacini Yes i'm listening to `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` to detect the device ...  but i thought it'll take some time till the `NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification` will stop my  NSFileManager from writing, which i thought is the problem ... @Volker but why is there an artifact of the unmounted device ? thats only happening (in my case) when there is a running file writing operation ...